# Extracting a value from SwiftDeferredNSDictionary by key in Objective C where key is Swift enum

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Given

```
enum MyKey: String {
    case aKey
}

let obj : [MyKey: Any] = [MyKey.aKey: "value"];
```

In my obj-c method I do:

```
[obj allKeys];
```

and then

```
for (id paramName in allKeys) {
    id paramValue = [obj valueForKey:paramName]; // Crashes here
    ...
}
```

And it crashes with an exception `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

How do I properly extract value by key in this case?

Comment: All ObjC APIs with dictionaries and enums I worked with required usage of `.rawValue` instead of `case` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that block enumerations works like a charm for Swift dictionaries in Objective c.

```
[obj enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id paramName, id paramValue, BOOL* stop) { }];
```